# How to scan characters in strings to match to another string in different column

Tags: python, pandas, knime

I have 2 columns of strings and I'd like to match the strings based on the first 3 characters in each string. Basically code that goes over every character of column 1 row 1 and compares it with rows in column 2 to find the best match.

IE: Row 1 Column 1 scans "p""a""s" and looks in Col2 for strings starting with "p""a""s" and so on for Row 2 Column 1.

I'm fairly new to python; my apologies.

Original Table (unsorted):

```
+-------------+---------+----------+
|  Row Index  |  Col1   |  Col2    |
+-------------+---------+----------+
| 1           | pasta   | sauce    |
| 2           | sauce   | orange   |
| 3           | orange  | pasta    |
+-------------+---------+----------+
```

Expected Table (after matching)

```
+-------------+---------+----------+
|  Row Index  |  Col1   |  Col2    |
+-------------+---------+----------+
| 1           | pasta   | pasta    |
| 2           | sauce   | sauce    |
| 3           | orange  | orange   |
+-------------+---------+----------+
```

I don't have any code to show as I'm not sure how to start this. Thanks.

Comment: What if there are multiple matches or no match at all?

Comment: In my case there will always be a match available. As for multiple matches that wont be an issue. The table provided is a simple example. Thanks.

Comment: From your example it looks like you can just duplicate `Col1` - do you have actual cases where only the first three characters match?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by " actual cases where only the first three characters match"; mind explaining?

Comment: In your example all strings are exact matches. But you want to scan based on the first three characters only. This would be necessary if you wanted to match words like "pasta" and "passive" together.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the fastest and cleanest solution, but will return what you're asking for:

```
df['Col3'] = df.Col1.apply(lambda x: [i for i in df.Col2 if i.startswith(x[:3])][0])
```

Comment: File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1472, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "<string>", line 4, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It means that you have words in column 1 without matches in column 2.